# dplyr filter in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I have a shiny app with a filter condition where I want to keep all values of a specific verctor if case1 is true for example, if not I do a filter with the input shiny .
I already did it with basic R and it works but now need to optimize my application by using dplyr.
Thank you

```
filter(
    ifelse(input$case1 == TRUE, 
           perimetre_commercial_estime %in% perimetres,
           perimetre_commercial_estime %in% input$perimetre
    )
 )
```

EDIT 1 :

The equivalent in base R is :

```
ifelse(input$case1 == TRUE,
       my.data <- my.data[my.data$perimetre_commercial_estime %in% perimetres, ],
       my.data <- my.data[my.data$perimetre_commercial_estime %in% input$perimetre, ]                   
)
```

EDIT 2 :

After jeff answered, I just remplaced the ifelse statement by if (condition) else and it works nicely ...any suggestion ?

```
  filter(if(input$case1 == TRUE){perimetre_commercial_estime %in% perimetres}
         else {perimetre_commercial_estime %in% input$perimetre}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bonjour MTB,

It sounds like you're putting your condition within the filter when it should be first. So:

```
if (condition)
  var <- filter(perimetre_commercial_estime %in% perimetres)
else
  var <- filter(perimetre_commercial_estime %in% input$perimetre)
```

Your post suggests the ifesle should be outside the filter() function; dplyr allows combination / exclusion logical arguments like && and || but within the same context.

Hope I understood the problem, I'm hunting down some unexpected shiny / dplyr behavior here myself...

Comment: Bonjour Jeff :)
Thanks for your answer, I remplaced the ifelse statement by if else statement in the dplyr filter and it seems to work ...strange !

Answer (score 1):

You shud have provided a reproducible example. As far as i understood, this simple example might help you.

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(a = sample(c("a","b"),10,replace=T),b = rnorm(10))
> x
   a          b
1  b -0.3862283
2  a  0.7916584
3  a -0.8751162
4  a -0.8164377
5  b -0.2174477
6  a -0.1998766
7  a  0.3356798
8  a  0.1569653
9  b  0.8326479
10 b -0.7936936

 x %>% filter(a == "a")

  a          b
1 a  0.7916584
2 a -0.8751162
3 a -0.8164377
4 a -0.1998766
5 a  0.3356798
6 a  0.1569653
```

Comment: Thank you koundy but it's not what i'm looking for. What i want is to filter with a condition on shiny thats why i use the ifelse statement. For example, for the variable "perimetre_commercial-estime" i want shiny to display what i choose modalities in the input$perimetre but when i check the "case1", i want to keep all modalities in "perimetres" vector.